# One to one class not updating in django: Gives Integrity Error

Tags: python, django

I am relatively new to Django and have been kinda struggling.
These are my three models below:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    siteID = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)

class EndDevice(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("edevID", "siteID")

    edevID = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    siteID = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deviceCategory = models.BigIntegerField()

class ThirdCombi(models.Model):
    siteID = models.OneToOneField(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    endDevice = models.TextField()
```

I am trying to make a table where one siteID displays all the edevID, which is the third model here. This does work using the following serializers.py

```
class CombiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ThirdCombi
        fields = ("siteID", "endDevice")

    def serialize(devices):
        d_list = []
        fields = ['edevID', 'siteID', 'deviceCategory']
        for device in devices:
            d_list.append(model_to_dict(device, fields=fields))
        return d_list
```

And the views.py as follow:

```
class CombiView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = ThirdCombi.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CombiSerializer
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):      
        try:
            s1 = Site.objects.get(siteID=kwargs["pk"])
            devices = EndDevice.objects.filter(siteID=s1) 
            a_site, created = ThirdCombi.objects.get_or_create(siteID=s1, endDevice=CombiSerializer.serialize(devices))
            return Response(CombiSerializer(a_site).data)
        except Site.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(
                data={
                    "message": "Site with id: {} does not exist".format(kwargs["pk"])},
                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

But once there is an update in EndDevice and I reload the page it gives me an integrity error and if I put an exception to integrity error, I cannot see the changes made in EndDevice reflected in ThirdCombi. I know why there is an integrity error because the siteID already exists and it tries to make a new one. I am not sure how to clear the old one in order to avoid the integrity error.

Any help will be appreciated in order to update the third table. Thanks.

Comment: Integrity error means you have not provided a data in any field and you don't have null equals True in your model as well. You need to share where integrity error is at.

Comment: IntegrityError at /site/home1/
UNIQUE constraint failed: registration_thirdcombi.siteID_id.That is what it says, but none of the fields are empty. Even checked the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Short: Use `update_or_create` instead of `get_or_create`.

```
ThirdCombi.objects.update_or_create(siteID=s1, defaults={"endDevice":CombiSerializer.serialize(devices)})
```

Go to bottom for full updated code.

> I know why there is an integrity error because the siteID already exists and it tries to make a new one.

You are right.

`get_or_create`: creates a new object if it doesn't find one with the passed parameters.

`OneToOneField`: If you have a model `Site` and another model `ThirdCombi` with a `OneToOneField` on `Site`, it means that `ThirdCombi` can only have utmost one object per `Site`

The problem is you are trying to create a new `ThirdCombi` with every `get` request.

Please observe:

Initially, there is a Site `s1` with 2 devices.

```
s1 = Site.objects.get(siteID=kwargs["pk"])
devices = EndDevice.objects.filter(siteID=s1) #2 devices
a_site, created = ThirdCombi.objects.get_or_create(siteID=s1, endDevice=CombiSerializer.serialize(devices)) #2 devices serialized "d1, d2"
```

Now, `get_or_create` creates a new `ThirdCombi` object for s1, since there is no `ThirdCombi` object for s1 initially. Let the created object be `third_combi1`.

> But once there is an update in EndDevice and I reload the page

See, you have updated the `EndDevice`. Now again observe:

We already have Site: `s1`, EndDevices: `d1, d2` and ThirdCombi: `third_combi1` for `s1`.
We cannot have another `third_combi2` for `s1`.

Since you updated EndDevices, let the current updated EndDevices be: `d1, d2, d3`

```
s1 = Site.objects.get(siteID=kwargs["pk"])
devices = EndDevice.objects.filter(siteID=s1) #3 devices
a_site, created = ThirdCombi.objects.get_or_create(siteID=s1, endDevice=CombiSerializer.serialize(devices)) #2 devices serialized "d1, d2, d3"
```

The problem here is `get_or_create` doesn't find an object with "d1, d2, d3". Hence it tries to create another `third_combi2` for 's1' with `d1, d2, d3`. Hence the integrity error.

Instead, use `update_or_create`.

`update_or_create`: update if an object with the given parameters exist, else create.

Your final code should be:

```
s1 = Site.objects.get(siteID=kwargs["pk"])
devices = EndDevice.objects.filter(siteID=s1) #2 devices
a_site, created = ThirdCombi.objects.update_or_create(siteID=s1, defaults={"endDevice":CombiSerializer.serialize(devices)})
```

Here, if there is a `ThirdCombi` object with `siteId=s1`, then update its `endDevice` field with the provided ones. Else create a new `ThirdCombi` object with the given data.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you recommended still gives me an inegrity error. I have found a work around solution which works well but not sure if I should be using it. And thank for the detailed explanation, that is what I thought.

Comment: I added the following:         except IntegrityError:
            ThirdCombi.objects.get(siteID=kwargs["pk"]).delete()
            a_site, created = ThirdCombi.objects.get_or_create(siteID=s1, endDevice=CombiSerializer.serialize(devices))
            print('ak:', a_site)
            return Response(CombiSerializer(a_site).data)
Not sure if it is a good way to do it though.

Comment: No. The exception type `Site.DoesNotExist` is not triggered. Because the Site `s1` exists. Did you try the final code at the bottom using `update_or_create`? using `defaults`?

Comment: Hi, didn't see the default part, it does work. Alternatively if I put an exception to IntegrityError, delete the existing field and create a new one works as well. Wasn't talking about Site.DoesNotExist(). But I believe your method is better than mine. Thanks